# java.security.KeyStoreException when trying to create HTTP instance

Tags: scala, akka-http

I am running a code in a WAS container and when I try to create the HTTP instance like:

```
val x = Http()
```

I am receiving the error below.

```
[3/28/18 12:59:45:614 MDT] 00000434 ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service Uncaught service() exception thrown by servlet com.avaya.ept.snapins.scalatemplate.web.RecordServlet: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: IBMJSSE2, class: com.ibm.jsse2.ag)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1628)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:248)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:176)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:30)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault(SSLContext.java:27)
    at com.typesafe.sslconfig.ssl.Ciphers$.java17RecommendedCiphers$lzycompute(Ciphers.scala:29)
    at com.typesafe.sslconfig.ssl.Ciphers$.java17RecommendedCiphers(Ciphers.scala:28)
    at com.typesafe.sslconfig.ssl.Ciphers$$anonfun$recommendedCiphers$2.apply(Ciphers.scala:26)
    at com.typesafe.sslconfig.ssl.Ciphers$$anonfun$recommendedCiphers$2.apply(Ciphers.scala:26)
    at com.typesafe.sslconfig.ssl.package$.foldVersion(package.scala:39)
    at com.typesafe.sslconfig.ssl.Ciphers$.recommendedCiphers(Ciphers.scala:24)
    at com.typesafe.sslconfig.akka.AkkaSSLConfig.configureCipherSuites(AkkaSSLConfig.scala:186)
    at com.typesafe.sslconfig.akka.AkkaSSLConfig.<init>(AkkaSSLConfig.scala:90)
    at com.typesafe.sslconfig.akka.AkkaSSLConfig$.createExtension(AkkaSSLConfig.scala:29)
    at com.typesafe.sslconfig.akka.AkkaSSLConfig$.createExtension(AkkaSSLConfig.scala:19)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.registerExtension(ActorSystem.scala:917)
    at akka.actor.ExtensionId$class.apply(Extension.scala:79)
    at com.typesafe.sslconfig.akka.AkkaSSLConfig$.apply(AkkaSSLConfig.scala:24)
    at com.typesafe.sslconfig.akka.AkkaSSLConfig$.apply(AkkaSSLConfig.scala:19)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.HttpExt.<init>(Http.scala:51)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.Http$.createExtension(Http.scala:928)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.Http$.createExtension(Http.scala:804)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.registerExtension(ActorSystem.scala:917)
    at akka.actor.ExtensionId$class.apply(Extension.scala:79)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.Http$.apply(Http.scala:923)
    at com.avaya.ept.snapins.scalatemplate.web.RecordServlet.doPost(RecordServlet.scala:94)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1232)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:781)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:480)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3951)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1014)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:287)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture$1.run(AsyncChannelFuture.java:205)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: IBMKeyManager: Problem accessing key store java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
        at com.ibm.jsse2.ae.a(ae.java:112)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.ag.g(ag.java:19)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.ag.<init>(ag.java:1)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor493.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:437)
        at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1606)
        ... 53 more
```

Is there any way to avoid the code tries to create an SSLContext instance?

I am saying that because I will just need to make an HTTP request using TCP protocol. I don't have any intention to use SSL in my code at this time.

Answer (score 0):

In reality it doesn't have a straightforward solution and it seems an issue in the library. Because of that I opened an issue as you can see on the link below.

https://github.com/akka/akka-http/issues/1978#issuecomment-378604822